# sqlalchemy: ObjectdereferencedError

Tags: python, database, sqlalchemy, flask

I have a flask app where I made a bunch of classes all with relationships to each other:

User
Course
Lecture
Note
Queue
Asset

So I'm trying to make a new lecture and note, and I have a method defined for each thing.

### create Note

```
def createPad(user,course,lecture):
    lecture.queues.first().users.append(user)
    # make new etherpad for user to wait in
    newNote = Note(dt) # init also creates a new pad at /p/groupID$noteID
    db.session.add(newNote)
    #db.session.commit()

    # add note to user, course, and lecture
    user.notes.append(newNote)
    course.notes.append(newNote)
    lecture.notes.append(newNote)
    db.session.commit()

return newNote
```

### createLecture

```
def createLecture(user, course):
    # create new lecture
    now = datetime.now()
    dt = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M")
    newLecture = Lecture(dt)
    db.session.add(newLecture)

    # add lecture to course, add new queue to lecture, add user to queue, add new user to lecture
    course.lectures.append(newLecture)
    newQueue = MatchQueue('neutral')
    db.session.add(newQueue)
    newLecture.users.append(user)


    # hook up the new queue to the user, lecture
    newQueue.users.append(user)
    newQueue.lecture = newLecture
    # put new lecture in correct course
    db.session.commit()

    newLecture.groupID = pad.createGroupIfNotExistsFor(newLecture.course.name+dt)['groupID']

    db.session.commit()
    return newLecture
```

which is all called from some controller logic

```
newlec = createLecture(user, courseobj)

# make new pad
newNote = createPad(user,courseobj,newlec)

# make lecture live
newLecture.live = True
db.session.commit()

redirect(somewhere)
```

This ends up throwing this error:

ObjectDereferencedError: Can't emit change event for attribute 'Queue.users' - parent object of type  has been garbage collected.

At `lecture.queues.first().users.append(user)` in `createPad`.

I have no clue what this means. I think I'm lacking some fundamental knowledge of sqlalchemy here (I am a sqlalchemy noob). What's going on?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
lecture.queues.first().users.append(user)
```

it means:

the first() method hits the database and produces an object, I'm not following your mappings but I have a guess its a Queue object.

then, you access the "users" collection on Queue.

At this point, Python itself **garbage collects** Queue - it is not referenced anywhere, once "users" has been returned.   This is how [reference counting](http://docs.python.org/2/extending/extending.html#reference-counts) garbage collection works.

Then you attempt to append a "user" to "users".  SQLAlchemy has to track the changes to all mapped attributes, if you were to say `Queue.name = "some name"`, SQLAlchemy needs to register that with the parent `Queue` object so it knows to flush it.   If you say `Queue.users.append(someuser)`, same idea, it needs to register the change event with the parent.

SQLAlchemy can't do this, because the `Queue` is gone.    Hence the message is raised.   SQLAlchemy has a [weakref](http://docs.python.org/2/library/weakref.html#weakref.ref) to the parent here so it knows exactly what has happened (and we can't prevent it because people get very upset when we create unnecessary [reference cycles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_counting#Dealing_with_reference_cycles) in their object models).

The solution is very easy and also easier to read which is to assign the query result to a variable:

```
queue = lecture.queues.first()
queue.users.append(user)
```

Answer (score 0):

I did a bunch of refactoring and put in the objects corresponding to some objects during instantiation, which made things a lot neater. Somehow the problem went away.

One thing I did differently was in my many-to-many relationships, I changed the backref to a db.backref():

```
courses = db.relationship('Course', secondary=courseTable, backref=db.backref('users', lazy='dynamic'))
lectures = db.relationship('Lecture', secondary=lectureTable, backref=db.backref('users', lazy='dynamic'))
notes = db.relationship('Note', secondary=noteTable, backref=db.backref('users', lazy='dynamic'))
queues = db.relationship('Queue', secondary=queueTable, backref=db.backref('users', lazy='dynamic'))
```